# using events and listeners properly with awt and setVisible()

Tags: java, events, swing, timer, awt

Below, i have two events that are supposed to occur at their specified intervals. but as odd as it is, one is just not occuring.

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private ActionListener listener;
private Timer t1;

private ActionListener listener2;
private Timer t2;

private String recentUpdate = "NULL";
private String recentPrinted ="NULL";

public MyFrame()
{
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();// gets the maximum size of the screen 
    setSize(d.width,(d.height/100)*10);//sets it to max. need to change this

    // this shit find the max size of screen and puts it bottom left
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    int x = (int)rect.getMinX();
    int y = (int)rect.getMaxY()-getHeight();
    setLocation(x,y-30);
    setTitle("ALERT::OUTAGE");
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    add(panel);

    listener = this;            //I THINK THIS just says wait for the timer
    t1 = new Timer(50000,listener); // time for each repaint
    t1.start();                 //go

    listener2 = this;           
    t2 = new Timer(10000,listener2); //time to wait before setting visible again
    t2.start();         

    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
repaint();
}

public void newUpdate(ActionEvent q)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Woopee!");
    //checkForNewUpdate();
}
```

Basically, I have a program which takes text from a webpage and displays it marquee style across the page. it repaints and moves 5 points left each time, allowing it to look fluid in animation.

When the frame is closed, it is hidden in the background. hide_on_close
when checkForUPdate is run, if there is an update then the page will reappear.

The probelm i have now is i can have 2 events and 2 timers. but im note sure how they work. How can i set it so that repaint will trigger on the Event and checkforUpdate() will occur on the ActionEvent q

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: pretty sure i know what tghe problem is. i dont know how to have both repaint and the setvisible event happen at different intervals. nice reading though

Answer (score 0):

Both timers end up triggering the same method, actionPerformed. There's nothing in your code to invoke newUpdate.

Comment: Im not even sure how i did that. how would i changed it so that timer 2 triggered newUpdate. something like listener 2 = newUpdate?

Comment: No. Typically you would have an if/switch statement in your actionPerformed method that would do things differently based on the soruce of the event. Another approach is to create inner classes (anonymous classes are good for this) that each implement the interface and assign an instance of each to the different timers.

Comment: not familiar with anonymous classes. If i understand the first approcah, then it presents a problem. because the repaint has to happen every 50ms. but the newupdate only every 5 mins or so. if i put the if/switch then wont i just come out with a slow repaint or a fast resource consuming newUpdate method.

Comment: the second approach im not sure i fully understand. if i create 2 inner classes of what exactly. timers? and what interface would they be implementing?  is there no easier way to have both events triggered but by differnet timers?

Answer (score 0):

needed to define the listeners. i didnt know how to combine timers with events

```
    listener = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            checkForNewUpdate();
        }           
    };
    //I THINK THIS just says wait for the timer
    t1 = new Timer(3000,listener); // time for each repaint
    t1.start();                 //go



    listener2 = new ActionListener()
    {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent q) 
          {repaint();}
    };
    t2 = new Timer(50,listener2); //time to wait before setting visible again
    t2.start();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    checkForNewUpdate();
    System.out.println("Woopee!");
    /**System.out.println(t2.getActionListeners().toString());*/ // just for testing
}
```